# Huge string replace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, replace, windows-1252

I've got a small JavaScript application that will parse files the user drops into the browser.  Recently I've discovered an issue with some non-english characters.  The file types that are dropped on here are using the Windows-1252 character set, so characters such as `ñ`, are actually coming through as `Ã±` and I must convert them all to the proper characters.

For example, I get `SeÃ±or` which should be `Señor` in Spanish.

I've found an [extremely useful website](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) with the collection of the characters, and their counterparts that I need to convert to.

I've condensed that down into two JavaScript arrays:

```
var toReplace = ["Ã€", "Ã", "Ã‚", "Ãƒ", "Ã„", "Ã…", "Ã†", "Ã‡", "Ãˆ", "Ã‰", "ÃŠ", "Ã‹", "ÃŒ", "Ã", "ÃŽ", "Ã", "Ã", "Ã‘", "Ã’", "Ã“", "Ã”", "Ã•", "Ã–", "Ã—", "Ã˜", "Ã™", "Ãš", "Ã›", "Ãœ", "Ã", "Ãž", "ÃŸ", "Ã", "Ã¡", "Ã¢", "Ã£", "Ã¤", "Ã¥", "Ã¦", "Ã§", "Ã¨", "Ã©", "Ãª", "Ã«", "Ã¬", "Ã­", "Ã®", "Ã¯", "Ã°", "Ã±", "Ã²", "Ã³", "Ã´", "Ãµ", "Ã¶", "Ã·", "Ã¸", "Ã¹", "Ãº", "Ã»", "Ã¼", "Ã½", "Ã¾", "Ã¿"];
var replaceWith = ["À", "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "×", "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ý", "Þ", "ß", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "þ", "ÿ"];
```

What would be the most efficient way to replace all characters from a paragraph in `toReplace` with it's counterpart (same index) in `replaceWith`?

I'm hoping this won't be too loop-heavy since it's not uncommon to drop over 100 files into this application that already does some heavy looping & parsing.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this instead of keeping these characters in arrays?

**EDIT** - I just realized I might need to replace with the unicode eqivilent instead.  Here's an array of the unicode characters in the same order:

```
var unicodeReplaceWith= ["\u00C0", "\u00C1", "\u00C2", "\u00C3", "\u00C4", "\u00C5", "\u00C6", "\u00C7", "\u00C8", "\u00C9", "\u00CA", "\u00CB", "\u00CC", "\u00CD", "\u00CE", "\u00CF", "\u00D0", "\u00D1", "\u00D2", "\u00D3", "\u00D4", "\u00D5", "\u00D6", "\u00D7", "\u00D8", "\u00D9", "\u00DA", "\u00DB", "\u00DC", "\u00DD", "\u00DE", "\u00DF", "\u00E0", "\u00E1", "\u00E2", "\u00E3", "\u00E4", "\u00E5", "\u00E6", "\u00E7", "\u00E8", "\u00E9", "\u00EA", "\u00EB", "\u00EC", "\u00ED", "\u00EE", "\u00EF", "\u00F0", "\u00F1", "\u00F2", "\u00F3", "\u00F4", "\u00F5", "\u00F6", "\u00F7", "\u00F8", "\u00F9", "\u00FA", "\u00FB", "\u00FC", "\u00FD", "\u00FE", "\u00FF"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about speed in JavaScript, or why this can't be configured correctly on the server, but here's one way to do it.

### [Interactive Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/gwIoG)

First we turn everything into an object, so we can look up translations.

```
var map = {};
for (var i=0; i<toReplace.length; i++) {
  map[toReplace[i]] = replaceWith[i];
}
```

Then we join our keys into a regular expression
<sup>(note: they must be sorted longest-first, code in the demo).</sup>

```
var expression = new RegExp(toReplace.join("|"), "g");
```

In the replace function, we can subsitute matches for results.  This is as simple as looking them up in our `map`.

```
function doReplace(source) {
  return source.replace(expression, function(m) {
    return map[m];
  });
}

var result = doReplace("SeÃ±or");
```

Comment: I have not tested performances, however I believe that a simple loop over every characters, checking if they are in the map and replacing accordingly is probably faster than using a regular expression.

Comment: It's possible, but if it's a large string; probably not.  Regular expressions are implemented in C/C++.  The only JavaScript code running is when a replacement needs to take place.  In a loop, you're calling several JavaScrpt functions per character in the data, regardless of how many need to be replaced.  Also, expressions without any quantifiers or look-arounds are pretty fast.

Comment: Quite interesting. However the code doesn't do the same replacement in your examples, since it checks a single letter for replacement and therefore, will not replace anything, but I believe that it would be even slower if it was.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but I'm haveing a **very** strang issue right now.  The array of strings in my JS file does not match the same file in my Chrome Dev tool.  This is not a cache issue.  --> http://i.imgur.com/F5Mt77B.png

Comment: **NOTE:** This solution will ONLY work when the `.js` file is saved in  Windows 1252 character encoding, or else you will have strange problems like in my screenshot above.

Comment: @ChrisBarr, okay, then it's probably best to encode them as character codes.

Comment: What do you suggest instead then?

Comment: @ChrisBarr, encode everything like `"\u00C0"`.  I think that should fix it, but I'm not entirely sure.  Encodings aren't my specialty.